# web.xml <transport-guarantee> not able to work in certain environment

Tags: java, web-applications, ssl, https

I have added this  transport-guarantee tag in the web.xml meaning that certain pages can only be accessed by https. But however this has an issue with environment that has web server and load balancer.

Apparently it does not redirect to the application with ssl port.

Seens like a firewall restriction.

Any advise anyone?

Comment: i am using Sun Application Server 8.1 Enterprise edition. You mean i can check what is the load balancer port for SSL in used? However there may be an issue as it might be used by one of the application domain in the app server

Comment: You can't check it, but you can configure it to explicitly tell the application server what the front end SSL port is, so that it knows to redirect to the correct port.

Answer (score 1):

Which container are you using? I believe some containers do allow you to specify the "front end" (i.e., web server, load balancer etc) SSL port in configuration.

I've done this for WebLogic, but I'm not sure if this requirement is explicitly speced out in the Java EE specs, or if all containers support it.